# pandas to_csv: suppress big number scientific notation in csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, scientific-notation

I'm trying to write data into csv. But big number is converting to exponential format.

My data is like 10 to 15 digit account number, mobile number, etc.
`Eg: 1083016404775 converts to 1.083016e+12`

Code being used:

```
itr = pd.read_sql_query(sql, connection, chunksize=chunksize)
    for i in itr:
      if count == 0:
        print i
        df.append(dd.from_pandas(i, chunksize=chunksize))
      else:
        i.index += count * chunksize
        df.append(dd.from_pandas(i, chunksize=chunksize))
      count += 1
    dfs = dd.concat(df)
    csv_file = os.path.join(csv_dir, str(tnl+'-*.csv'))
    csv_file_name = os.path.join(csv_dir, str(tnl+'.csv'))
    dfs.to_csv(csv_file,index=False,encoding='utf-8')

  header_saved=False
  filenames = glob(csv_file)
  ddf = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f,header = 0) for f in filenames))
  ddf.to_csv(csv_file_name,index=False,encoding='utf-8')
  for hgx in filenames:
    os.remove(hgx)
```

I even tried using `float_format='{:f}'.format` but i'm getting the error:
`Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'`

Also tried `pd.set_option('precision',2)` but no luck

Comment: What is the datatype in the server? Also - it's confusing why you're chunking stuff to only concat it all anyway - seems to be defeating the purpose of what I imagine you're trying to do... and is `dd` a reference to something in dask dataframe - it doesn't appear to be referenced otherwise...

Comment: After you read the csv, just convert the big number to int64 format.

Comment: @JonClements datatype is number in server. i'm chunking it because the read_sql has some limitations on the data.

Comment: Storing a phone number as an actual number is an interesting way to lose information :)

Comment: That being said - can't you just cast it as a string in your sql so everything else that follows just treats it as a string and that should avoid all the issues here...

Comment: Also - have you checked the DB data itself and made sure you just haven't lost the necessary information to start with by the choice of column type?

Comment: @JonClements i'm actually looping them with table names. are you suggesting to convert them in query? the DB has the data in correct format

Comment: You need to identify the point you're getting the 1.083016e+12 as that if you don't catch it early enough, you'll only get back to 1083016000000.0 - which isn't what you want. I think if you make sure you cast first in the query and see what can come from that - you might be okay-ish.

Comment: @JonClements, After getting this data into a number of glob files (a-0.csv,a-1.csv), I'm combining the chunk files into a single file(a.csv). I'm guessing that this is read_csv is reading storing it in an exponential format. Any idea how to suppress this

Comment: Hi @JonClements, tried using a different method for merging the csv files. Still facing the same issue. looks like the read_sql_query function converts the data in such(1.083016e+12) format.